# what is alternative class for TexturePaint.java class in codenameone?

Tags: java, awt, codenameone

I want to use [TexturePaint.java](https://github.com/shannah/codenameone-avian/blob/master/jdk7u-dev/jdk/src/share/classes/java/awt/TexturePaint.java)  class in my codenameone project is there any implementation for this class by codenameone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment.

Codename One has a new Shape API which includes strokes, fills but not paints (gradient or texture based). Both of these are under consideration for a future update so if you have common use cases and an enterprise/pro account you should probably write to support about that.